# KARATE: print statement doesn't write to console with log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, log4j2, karate

I have spring boot application and use karate for testing.
I used log4j2 for logging. Karate use logback as a log library.
I found [this link](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/6de466bdcf105d72450a40cf31b8adb5c043037d/karate-demo/README.md#log4j-config-file) for basic configuration of log4j2 with karate. But unfortunately print statement in the feature file is not written to console.

This is my Simple test to print to console.

```
Scenario: Print to Console
    * print 'Hello Word'
```

Log4j2.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

As you see bellow I excluded logback dependecies from karate with this code

```
testImplementation('com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:0.9.6') {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    testImplementation('com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.6') {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
```

Gradle build file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"
    //id 'war'
}
group = 'test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz'){
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.zalando:jackson-datatype-money:1.2.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'


    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.0.Final'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.9.13'
    implementation group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'

    implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.9'
    implementation 'org.javamoney:moneta:1.4.2'

    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'


    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.0.Final'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation('com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:0.9.6') {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    testImplementation('com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.6') {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'

}

test {

    useJUnitPlatform()
    environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: "test"
}

bootRun {
    environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: "dev"
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RunAllKarateTest  {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("server.port", String.valueOf(port));
    }

    @Karate.Test
    Karate runAll() {
        return Karate.run().relativeTo(getClass());
    }

}
```

Karate Config

```
function fn() {

   var port = karate.properties['server.port'];
   if (!port) {
       port = 8080;
     }
    var config = {
        baseUrl : 'http://localhost:'+port,
        uuid: function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' },
        isoDateTime: function(){ return java.time.OffsetDateTime.now().format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)}
    };


    return config;
}
```

This is the report screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it start working after changing configuration of log4j2.properties files

**New configuration as follows:**

```
appenders = console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout


rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```